# How to find an entity name of a guid in Microsoft Dynamics 365 with c#?

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-365

I have a guid and I don't know that's for which entity.
How can I find owned entity name?
for example, there is a guid code: **7487cd8b-a0a2-eb11-b81e-005056a460ec**. but what's the entity name?

Comment: Why do you think the GUID is an entity ID? Where did you find it? This question is far too broad.

Comment: I know it! I want to find a guid that is in a regardingobjectid field. so that's a guid code but i don't know which entity used in regardingobject field.

Comment: when you have a `regardingobjectid`, you also have a `regardingobjecttypecode` in the same row. Look there first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How did you come across this Guid?

In Dynamics, you should **never** have a record Guid without its entity/logical name. They almost always come together - if you don't see it, it's probably not too far!

- In C# Dynamics SDK, lookup fields should always be EntityReference objects.
- (The trickiest) If you're using the Web API HTTP requests, make sure to [include annotations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/developer/data-platform/webapi/query-data-web-api#bkmk_lookupProperty) in your request header:

```
Accept: application/json  
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8  
OData-MaxVersion: 4.0  
OData-Version: 4.0  
Prefer: odata.include-annotations="*"
```

This will include additional fields:

```
_regardingobjectid_value@Microsoft.Dynamics.CRM.lookuplogicalname:"new_myentity",
_regardingobjectid_value:"ad2d51c9-1de2-449d-b80a-76232503aacf",
```

- If using Xrm.WebAPI, the annotations should be included by default.
- In model-driven form javascript, formContext.getAttribute("regardingobjectid").getValue() will give you an array of Xrm.LookupValue objects containing both.

```
entityType: "new_myentity", id: "{C8FE3743-2730-4625-85D5-325837015D8B}", name: "Name"}
```

In a related note, I think it's a good idea to never put guids in variables, parameters or otherwise -- they are rather meaningless on their own as you have found -- always carry around EntityReference / Xrm.LookupValue objects instead.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to write a GUID search yourself you could use  [XrmToolBox](https://www.xrmtoolbox.com/) tool [Universal Search](https://github.com/mikefactorial/MikeFactorial.XTB.Plugins.UniversalSearch). You enter a GUID and search across entities.

1. Install [XrmToolBox](https://www.xrmtoolbox.com/)
2. Install [Universal Search](https://github.com/mikefactorial/MikeFactorial.XTB.Plugins.UniversalSearch) tool *inside* [XrmToolBox](https://www.xrmtoolbox.com/)
3. Open [Universal Search](https://github.com/mikefactorial/MikeFactorial.XTB.Plugins.UniversalSearch) and enter your GUID in the **Search Criteria** box
4. Select one or more entities to search using the panel on left. Since you know your ID is in a regardingobjectid field, you ***may*** be able to limit your search to activity entities.
5. If this doesn't work you can search across all entities by using the **Check All/None** button, but be aware this is a long running and slow process

[Universal Search XrmToolBox tool with annotations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gkqTG.png) (low rep so can't post inline images)

Answer (score 0):

This maybe a rare and costly requirement :) You can use this code snippet for the exact purpose. [Thanks to "Guid"o](https://www.crmanswers.net/2013/04/retrieve-entity-logical-name-from.html)

```
// Retrieve Metadata for all entities
RetrieveAllEntitiesRequest allEntitiesRequest = new RetrieveAllEntitiesRequest();
allEntitiesRequest.EntityFilters = EntityFilters.Entity;
allEntitiesRequest.RetrieveAsIfPublished = true;
RetrieveAllEntitiesResponse allEntitiesResponse = (RetrieveAllEntitiesResponse)service.Execute(allEntitiesRequest);

// Record ID to check
Guid checkId = new Guid("541067bd-4db1-2208-e5b0-a601ead56d03");

string entityLogicalName = string.Empty;
foreach (EntityMetadata entityMetadata in allEntitiesResponse.EntityMetadata)
{
    try
    {
        // Try to retrieve the record from the current entity
        Entity test = service.Retrieve(entityMetadata.LogicalName, checkId, new ColumnSet(entityMetadata.PrimaryIdAttribute));
        // if the previous instruction didn't throw an exception means that the record exists.
        entityLogicalName = entityMetadata.LogicalName;
        break;
    }
    catch { }
}
if (entityLogicalName != string.Empty)
{
    string foundMessage = string.Format("Record with ID {0} belongs to entity {1}", checkId.ToString(), entityLogicalName);
    Console.WriteLine(foundMessage);
}
else
{
    string notFoundMessage = string.Format("Record with ID {0} not found in any entity", checkId.ToString());
    Console.WriteLine(notFoundMessage);
}
```

Comment: thanks for answer, Arun.  but this is a very public and costly way, as you said.
maybe there is no easier way for find this issue.

Comment: @DavoodRamezani maybe you can try alternate key using human readable unique number like con-12345 for contact and so on.. instead of guid